# My Looping Values are Messed Up

Tags: java, loops, user-interface, jtextarea

I need help with my loop, it only prints the last line : " Froakie " in the textArea, and, I've tried other methods, please help. :) The code is supposed to print every single Pokemon status into the textArea, but, it only puts it Froakie's data entry.

```
String[][] firstevolutiondata = {    
                {"Pikachu", "Electric", "1", "Kanto", "Yellow", "35", "55", "90", "40", "Thunderstone", "1"},
                {"Charmander", "Fire", "1", "Kanto", "Red, Blue, Green, Fire Red, Leaf Green", "39", "52", "65", "43", "Level 16", "1"},
                {"Bulbasaur", "Grass", "1", "Kanto", "Red, Blue, Green, Fire Red, Leaf Green", "45", "49", "45", "49", "Level 16", "1"}
    };

private static void printstats(int n, int x, String texts, String[] columnNames, String [][] firstevolutiondata) {
n = 0;

while ( n < 10 ) {

texts = texts + columnNames[n] + " : " + firstevolutiondata[x][n] + "  \n";
textArea.setText(texts);
n++;
}
 texts = texts + "\n";
 textArea.setText(texts);
 texts = texts + "\n";
 textArea.setText(texts);

}
```

Comment: Don't mind the second evolution data.

Comment: Is this *really* the smallest code necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I love pokemon and I like to see their evolutions and all. But **not here**. Please provide minimal code which can demonstrate your problem. Posting all the code isn't helpful.

Comment: I may have posted too much, heh. :/ I'm new to Stack Overflow, sorry.

Comment: The problems are presented : private static void printstats(int n, int x, String texts, String[] columnNames, String [][] firstevolutiondata) {

                n = 0;

                while ( n < 10 ) {

            texts = texts + columnNames[n] + " : " + firstevolutiondata[x][n] + "  \n";
            textArea.setText(texts);
                    n++;

                }

                texts = texts + "\n";
                textArea.setText(texts);
                texts = texts + "\n";
                textArea.setText(texts);

        }

Comment: @C_Tee You can always edit your question. Please provide only the code which you want to and has a problem in it. **Edit the question, not comment it**

Comment: The `JTextArea.setText(...)` method doesn't append the text, it replaces it, try the `JTextArea.append(...)` method.

Comment: Hi guys! Thanks all of you, for helping me out, I finally figured it out! Have a nice day, all. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using `setText()` in your `printStats` method. Use `append()` ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29)) or move `textArea.setText(texts);` below the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, your class has too many lines. You can safe a lot of lines and improve readability using some loops to construct variables and storing variables in any structure (List, Set...).

As far as your question is concerned, the problem is here:

```
while ( n < 10 ) {

        texts = texts + columnNames[n] + " : " + firstevolutiondata[x][n] + "  \n";
        textArea.setText(texts);
}
```

You're setting a value inside your `textArea` object every time the loop executes an iteration. Use append instead of setter method.